# how to center a box using blueprint css framework

Tags: css, compass-sass, blueprint-css

My `_base.scss` contains the following

```
$blueprint-grid-columns: 12;
$blueprint-container-size: 750px;
$blueprint-grid-margin: 0px;
// Use this to calculate the width based on the total width.
// Or you can set $blueprint-grid-width to a fixed value and unset $blueprint-container-size -- it will be calculated for you.
$blueprint-grid-width: ($blueprint-container-size + $blueprint-grid-margin) / $blueprint-grid-columns - $blueprint-grid-margin;
```

In my page I have a big box that is `750 px` wide

```
#big-box {
  @include container;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 15px;
  min-height: 550px;
}
```

inside this box I want to have a box that is aligned in center but I can't seem to get this done. Below is my code

```
#login{
  @include container;
  margin-top: 15px;
  @include column(11);
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
```

what should I do so that the `#login` box is in the middle?

[Image](http://i52.tinypic.com/2wpjakm.png) of how it looks now:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this fails is that the `column` mixin not only sets the width of the element, but also floats it left and applies a right margin (unless it's the last column, which has no margin).  `span` is used internally by the `column` mixin to set the width.  So you can use `span` here to simply set the width without getting the float and margin that `column` would add.

Check out the compass blueprint grid implementation here:
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets/blueprint/_grid.scss

So if you use `span` instead of `column`, you just get the width you want.  Then you can apply `margin: 0 auto;` to get the centering you desire.  `container` sets this as well, though typically you want to use `container` as it's intended in blueprint, as a style applied to top level layout elements.  If you just apply the margin yourself you don't need to override the grid width that `container` sets.

The other, "grid" way to fix this would be to prepend/append columns to push the box to the center.  E.g. if your layout was 19 across and the box was 11 wide, you might `@include prepend(4);` To add 4 columns of width to the left side of the box.

```
#login {
  // Don't include container.  In blueprint "container" means this is an outer
  // container for the grid, and has the grid width, centered on the page.
  // @include container;

  @include column(11);

  // I have no idea how many columns your page has, but if it had 19, 4 left columns 
  // would effectively center the div. | 4 + 11 + 4 |.
  // Adjust to your real layout.
  @include prepend(4);
}
```

Comment: `width: span(11);` worked great. now the width of that box is automatically set to `686.667 px` I am new to blueprint CSS. could you elaborate how setting span(11) fixed the issue?